# What does it mean to treat $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[My textbook](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong) (“Linear Algebra Done Wrong” by Sergei Treil) says (on page 27 of the PDF file):

> The set $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers can be canonically identified with the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ by treating each $z = x+iy$ as a column $(x,y)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Does this just mean that you can either represent a complex number $a+ib$ as $(a,b)$, a column in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or alternative as just $(a+ib)$, a one dimensional vector in $\mathbb{C}^1$? Does it have any other implications? For example, are the scalars in both cases still complex numbers?

The text later writes:

> Treating $\mathbb{C}$ as the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$…

Is this referring to the same canonical identification as above? The way its written confuses me and makes me think because we're treating $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space the scalars can no longer be complex numbers, but is this wrong?

Finally, it defines a linear transformation and asks the question:

> Show that this transformation is not a linear transformation in the complex vectors space $\mathbb{C}$, but if we treat $\mathbb{C}$ as the real vector space $\mathbb{R^2}$ then it is a linear transformation there (i.e., that it is a real linear but not complex linear transformation.

I think I'm understanding this wrong. If treating the vector spaces as real or complex simply means representing them differently (as a tuple vs a 1d vector), shouldn't this not change the linearity of any transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we say that we are treating a complex vector space $V$ as a real vector space, then the only scalars that we use are real numbers. So, $\mathbb C$, which is a one-dimensional complex vector space, can also be seen as a two-dimensional real vector space.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm still a little confused though. What determines whether the entries of the vector itself are complex or real? For instance, my understanding is now that you the implication of treating ℂ as a complex vector space is that the scalars are complex. Does this also mean that the entries of the vectors are complex? Couldn't the scalars be complex but we still represent every complex number as a tuple of real numbers?

Comment: Yes, we can. Your book is simply explaining *why* is it that, if we see $\mathbb C$ as a real vector space, then it is ismorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. It does this by the process of defining such an isomorphism:$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb C&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R^2\\a+bi&\mapsto&\binom ab.\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

A vector space is always over some field of scalars. A real vector space takes this field to be $\Bbb R$; a complex vector space takes this field to be $\Bbb C$. You may treat $\Bbb C$ as $1$-dimensional over $\Bbb C$, with the scalars being complex, or as $2$-dimensional over $\Bbb R$, with the scalars being real. (In fact, you may treat $\Bbb C^n$ as $n$-dimensional over $\Bbb C$, with the scalars being complex, or as $2n$-dimensional over $\Bbb R$, with the scalars being real.)

A transformation on $\Bbb C$ might be linear only in the real case. Take complex conjugation: over $\Bbb R$ it's just the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)$, but over $\Bbb C$ it's not linear at all, because there's no $k\in\Bbb C$ for which $z^\ast$ is identically $kz$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm still a little confused though. What determines whether the entries of the vector itself are complex or real? For instance, you note the implication of treating $\mathbb{C}$ as a complex vector space is that the scalars are complex. Does this also mean that the entries of the vectors are complex? Couldn't the scalars be complex but we still represent every complex number as a tuple of real numbers?

Comment: @EnriqueC The "entries" are just scalars! So in the real case, they have to be real numbers. That's why $\Bbb C$ ends up $2$-dimensional; its basis is $\{1,\,i\}$. Thus $(x1+yi)^\ast=(x1-yi)$ may be rewritten as $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
-y
\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: I think I finally understand. So we can represent complex numbers as 1D vector with  entries being complex which can have complex scalars, or as 2D vector with entries being real, in which case scalars need to be real because otherwise scalar closure would be violated. And its just a fact that a transformation might be linear with one representation but not the other? Does all this make sense? Thanks so much for your help so far.

Comment: @EnriqueC That's right, yes.